# Access VBA Script Slowing Down

Tags: vba, ms-access

Apologies, but I am a total and complete VBA noob. Microsoft's support folks wrote a script in two parts for our company that takes longer and longer to run every time we run it. The reason for this is because the table keeps getting longer, and each part of the script just runs from the start and does it's thing on every row until it gets to the end. Basically, it looks at a row, makes an evaluation of the data, and then enters a value in an empty cell within that row.

What would be nice is if each part of the script had a preamble that would first find the first empty cell and then start doing its analysis. I hope that makes sense. I've attached the script here. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

```
Public Function update_maintable() As Boolean
Dim sUsernames() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim flg As Boolean, flgDebug As Boolean
Dim sLastStatus As String
flg = False
ReDim sUsernames(1, 0)

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
rs2.Open "SELECT * FROM Orders", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
Do While Not rs2.EOF
    For i = CLng(1) To UBound(sUsernames, 2)
        Debug.Print sUsernames(0, i)
        If rs2("first name") & rs2("last name") & rs2("billing state") = sUsernames(0, i) Then
            flg = True
            rs2("customer status") = "R"
        End If
    Next
    If flg = False And rs2("username") <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve sUsernames(1, UBound(sUsernames, 2) + 1)
        sUsernames(0, UBound(sUsernames, 2)) = rs2("first name") & rs2("last name") & rs2("billing state")
        sUsernames(1, UBound(sUsernames, 2)) = rs2("order#")
        rs2("customer status") = "N"
    End If
    flg = False
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop
Debug.Print "Number of Rows in Array: " & UBound(sUsernames, 2) + 1
Debug.Print "Number of columns in Array: " & UBound(sUsernames, 1) + 1

Set cn = Nothing
UpdateIndividualOrders
MsgBox "Customer Status field has been updated", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Table Updated"
update_maintable = True


End Function

Public Function UpdateIndividualOrders() As Boolean
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sLastStatus As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset

rs1.Open "Select * from Orders where Orders.[Customer Status]<>"""" AND Orders.[Customer Status] Is Not Null", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
Do While Not rs1.EOF
    sLastStatus = rs1("customer status")
    rs2.Open "UPDATE Orders SET Orders.[Customer Status] = """ & sLastStatus & """ WHERE Orders.[Order#]=" & CInt(rs1("Order#")) & ";", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
    rs1.MoveNext
Loop

UpdateIndividualOrders = True

End Function

Public Function update_maintable2() As Boolean
Dim sUsernames() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim flg As Boolean, flgDebug As Boolean
Dim sLastStatus As String
flg = False
ReDim sSKUs(1, 0)

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
rs2.Open "SELECT * FROM Orders", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
Do While Not rs2.EOF
    For i = CLng(1) To UBound(sSKUs, 2)
        Debug.Print sSKUs(0, i)
        If rs2("first name") & rs2("last name") & rs2("billing state") & rs2("sku") = sSKUs(0, i) Then
            flg = True
            rs2("repeating purchase") = "Y"
        End If
    Next
    If flg = False And rs2("username") <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve sSKUs(1, UBound(sSKUs, 2) + 1)
        sSKUs(0, UBound(sSKUs, 2)) = rs2("first name") & rs2("last name") & rs2("billing state") & rs2("sku")
        rs2("repeating purchase") = "N"
    End If
    flg = False
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop
Debug.Print "Number of Rows in Array: " & UBound(sSKUs, 2) + 1
Debug.Print "Number of columns in Array: " & UBound(sSKUs, 1) + 1

Set cn = Nothing
UpdateIndividualOrders
MsgBox "Repeating Purchase field has been updated", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Table Updated"
update_maintable2 = True


End Function
```

Comment: `rs2.Open "SELECT * FROM Orders where [customer status] is null", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic`

Comment: There are numerous odd things about these functions, but you're not even specifying which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and also check out [mcve], and [ask]...

Comment: Apologies for the oddities, @Erik. The problem is, I can barely understand code.  
@Tim: it would seem I should be replacing the first

    `<pre>rs2.Open "SELECT * FROM Orders", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic<code>`  

with  

    `<pre>rs2.Open "SELECT * FROM Orders where [customer status] is null", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic<code>`  

and the second instance with

    `<pre>rs2.Open "SELECT * FROM Orders where [repeating purchase] is null", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic<code>`

?

Comment: Well, it didn't work.. both the [customer status] and [repeating purchase] started spitting out N's where the values should have been "R" or "Y".

Comment: To be honest I didn't read all the code, just the first sub.  Without knowing exactly what the code is supposed to do it's difficult to make "safe" suggestions for improving performance.  Your idea of finding the "first empty cell" doesn't translate to Access as it might to an Excel sheet though: in a database table it's not useful to think of records being in any particular order: instead you use SQL to pull out the records of interest and order them in a useful way.

Comment: There are no `Update` or `UpdateBatch` calls in your code (and as @ErikvonAsmuth notes, a bunch of other odd things) so does it actually work at all?  If this was written by professionals then it doesn't seem like they did a great job.

Comment: There are 3 functions here: update_maintable; update_maintable2; and UpdateIndividualOrders. The first two loop through all of the rows in your Orders table, build some arrays, dump information to the immediate window via Debug.Print, and then call UpdateIndividualOrders. In UpdateIndividualOrders, you again loop through all of the rows in the Orders table and, it appears, try to update Customer Status to whatever the Customer Status is already?! Looping all rows is very inefficient and will get slower as you are seeing. This could probably be done with straight SQL and be much faster.